# AWS - DJANGO - Error in formatting: OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, django-database

I have just setup a Django app on aws beanstalk with PostgreSQL 9.4.7. My database settings are as follows;

```
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
```

I have installed psycopg2.

AWS application installation completed successfully however when i opened by index page I received the following error.

```
Exception Type: RuntimeError
Exception Value:    
Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.
```

Further digging into the exception page I found this error

```
**Variable**    
my_list 

**Value**
Error in formatting: OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

**request** 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/new/'>
```

my_list is the variable defined in the index page view.

Further down the page I can see the DB values are updated correctly.

to check if there was some issue with the password I tried accessing aws RDS via pgadmin and was able to do so successfully so no issues there.

I have tried a lot of things but was not able to find a solution so need some assistance please.

EDIT: I have also checked the tables after connecting with pgadmin and can confirm that all the tables have been created through migrate command (created in aws .config file) on the aws database. Just thought of sharing this in case this is helpful.

EDIT 2: so on the error page if I go down to the settings section I can see both id and password reflecting (pass in ******** form). However in the Traceback section I can see that password is None but rest of the info is there and this error is;

```
/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
```

EDIT3: so I get everything from the db except for the password and I checked my env file found in /opt/python/current on aws ssh instance and found it had all the export settings correctly listed including the password.

To be more explicit, below I have mentioned the exception detail I get on traceback on the web page detail under

> /opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py
>   in connect
>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)

```
**Variable  Value** 

database    'xxx' - This is correct

items      [('dbname', 'xxx'), This is correct
           ('user', 'xxxxx'), This is correct
           ('host', 'xxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com'), This is correct
           ('port', '5432')]

k          'port'

kwargs     {}

connection_factory  None

dsn        'dbname=xxxx user=xxxx host=xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com port=5432' This is correct

host       'xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com' This is correct

user       'xxxxx'  This is correct

v          '5432' async     False

**password  None** **THIS IT NOT CORRECT**

port       '5432'

cursor_factory  None
```

Comment: if you change RDS_HOSTNAME value, what error you get?..

Comment: @VaoTsun when I just enter random value in HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'] for this test I entered os.environ['abc'] I got the internal server error page and on the aws error log I got the following error;  File "/opt/python/run/baselinenv/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__ raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'abc'.

Comment: @VaoTsun  I also tried this example 'HOST': 'abcd' and got "Error in formatting: OperationalError: could not translate host name "abcd" to address: Name or service not known". and also the same runtime error of "Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually."

Comment: @VaoTsun I also completely removed the host and this is the error I got; Error in formatting: OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?. Also, the same runtime error Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.

Comment: I meant to check if you use OS `env`. you run it under linux?.. what you see when running `env | grep RDS`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun sorry I am new to this. Yes, I use linux on aws. when the run this command there is no response command prompt and it moves to thew new line. If it is convenient we can jump on a chat.

Comment: then I believe the code with configuration you provided is skipped on launch. try running `export PGPASSWORD=your_postgres_password` before you launch Django

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111489/discussion-between-codingmehelp-and-vao-tsun).

Comment: @VaoTsun Can you please let me where exactly i need to place this. I added it to the settings file but it gave me an error.

Comment: @VaoTsun et all finally was able to add the same but no help. still the same issue. I have also updated my question with EDIT 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-rds.html

In your case I woould try going for

> 2. Configure your Amazon RDS DB security group to allow access from the Amazon EC2 security group used by your Elastic Beanstalk
>      application

part

**Update:**
don't forget to backslash variables values like RDS_PASSWORD in os environment. Eg `export RDS_PASSWORD="pa$$word"` should become `export RDS_PASSWORD="pa\$\$word"`

to do this go to;
on ssh ec2 instance and go to file

> /opt/python/current

. This dir has one app directory which holds the django app and an env file. "nano env" and it shows lot of export statements go to the RDS_PASSWORD line and add the blackslash pass to it.

export RDS_PASSWORD="pa\$\$word". Save the file.

Then restart the app on aws and it works like a charm.

Comment: thanks for your response. I created a new security even though I had already created one assigned it to the db security group and also to EC2 instance rebooted everything and it still didn't work.

Comment: I sshed into the aws instance and there is no file named .pgpass. do I need to create one?

Comment: Thanks the error was with the backslash. something so small take away so many hours. Thanks you for the assistance :). It is not allowing me to give the bounty right now, I have to wait for 21 hours it says. I will do so accordingly.